# How do I write a "formula" in the Google Sheets filter widget?

Tags: google-sheets

I know I can do this with formulas, but I'd like to understand how to do it using the popup filter tool (since I'm constantly changing it).

This thing, for reference:

[image: Google Filter Widget - Blank]

Ordinarily, I can get away with entering the string I want in the "Value or formula" window, like so...

[image: Google Filter Widget - String]

The above works AS LONG AS the exact string I type matches a sub-string in the cell. However, every now and then I want to do something like this...

[image: Google Filter Widget - Non-working Formula]

But that doesn't work.

I've tried all sorts of "formulas", like `"foo" && "bar"` or `="foo" + "bar"`

But of course those don't work either... It doesn't seem to make sense to use the `=filter(...)` formula, as that requires a range that is already defined by the filter widget itself. I haven't had any luck with that either.

Can anyone give me an example of (or a link to) an `AND` search 'formula' I can type into that window that would actually include all of the following 'cells':

```
foo bar
foo banana bar
bar foo
this foo that bar
```

And in case others find this question, it might be nice to see an `OR` search formula as well

Answer (score 2):

#### Custom Formula:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1,"(?iU)(foo.*bar)|(bar.*foo)")
```

Apply to `A1:A5`

[Click here](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm0TjGZfW4x3pg/?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

## OR Logic

**Hardcode the list**

You may try custom formula:

`=ISNA(MATCH(A2,{"foo", "bar", "banana"},))=false`

You may add any number of items inside [`array { }`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) in double quotes: "that", "boo", ...

**Add the list into separate column**

I've added a list in column G:

```
foo
bar
banana
```

and then applied the formula:

`=ISNA(MATCH(A2, G:G ,))=false`

The filter did not adjust when I added values in col G, I needed to click on the filter and OK button to refresh it.

## AND Logic

For and logic [`regex`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292) may be handy, as @i-i has suggested.